# How can I change the value stored in local macro from string to numeric?

Tags: types, global, stata, local, stata-macros

I want to generate a variable with lagged year depending on the year stored in  the `"$S_DATE"` macro. I have stored the year in a macro named `date`:

```
. local date substr("$S_DATE",8,.)
. display `date'
  2015
```

And I want to generate the new variable with:

```
gen start_year =`date'- y_passed
```

where `y_passed` is a variable containing integers from 1 to 10.

However, I get:

```
. gen start_year = `date' - y_passed
type mismatch
r(109);
```

I know this happens because the macro stored is a string.

How can I change the value stored in local macro from string to numeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `=`, then Stata will evaluate the expression that defines local `date`:

```
clear
set more off

set obs 10
gen y_passed = _n

local date = substr("$S_DATE",8,.)
display `date'

gen start_year = `date' - y_passed

list
```

Otherwise, the local just holds a string, but not a number in a string type! See

```
. local date substr("$S_DATE",8,.)

. display `"`date'"'
substr("14 May 2015",8,.)
```

The confusion is because `display` will evaluate for you. In reality,

```
display `date'
```

expands to

```
display substr("14 May 2015",8,.)
```

and the latter results in

```
2015
```

Comment: In this case `yofd(daily("$S_DATE", "DMY"))` yields a numeric value for the current year from the current system date.